# How to set static files path in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I deployed war file (srsmobile.war) in tomcat server under webapps folder. My static files are placed in Tomcat/webapps/SRSFILES folder. After tomcat running we are able to access our application but assets which are in SRSFILES folder not loaded.

The problem is for my assets path is should be like below:

```
/SRSFILES/common.js
```

But after running path is:

```
/SRSMOBILE/SRSFILES/common.js
```

Why SRSMOBILE is added to my path?

Comment: Please respond to my question

Comment: And your code (which constructs the URL) is? (Most probably the `/SRSMOBILE` part is added, because it is the context path, i.e. name of your web application. But without seeing your code, we can only guess.)

Comment: Can i know,In which files context paths is setting?